# Laravel 9 | Mailgun saying "Password is not set"

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun, laravel-9, laravel-sail

**I'm trying to setup an email system through my Laravel app via Mailgun, here's my .env file
(sensitive info is replaced of course)**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=***
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=***

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=***
DB_USERNAME=***
DB_PASSWORD=***

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@*****.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=(provided default password for this domain)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=*****@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=*****.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=(I'm not sure what to put here, I tried the API key provided when I signed up and also the Mailgun password)

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

SCOUT_DRIVER=meilisearch
MEILISEARCH_HOST=http://meilisearch:7700
```

**The error here is showing up pretty much no matter what I've tried changing. I can also supply the mail.php, controller, etc. if needed. I feel like it might be much simpler than that though.**

Comment: Can you provide the full error message, please?

Comment: @GabeCurran are you sure that your application uses this exact `.env` options?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had a super busy week/weekend. Here's the full error.
https://imgur.com/a/NHds8fg

Also yes, I'm pretty sure it is using the .env settings